# Gurobi problem when managing range constraint

Tags: python, range, gurobi

So, I have some constraints in a gurobi-python model,

```
for i in range():
    for j in range():
        for k in range():
         model.addConstr( w[j,k] >= w[i,k] + sd[j] + (x[i,j,k] - 1)*M )
         model.addConstr( w[j,k] <= v )
```

**x** is a binary variable, **w** is an integer variable.  **v** and **sd** are parameters( which are both precise integers I prepared beforehand).

What I want to do is to collect minimum value of each w[j,k].

How should I manage this?

I really appreciate for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an objective function that minimizes the sum of `w[j,k]`. An optimal solution then implies that there is no other assignment of `w[j,k]` with a smaller value.

This is how you could do it:

```
model.setObjective(sum(w[j,k] for j in range(?) for k in range(?))
```

You can also just set the objective coefficients of every `w[j,k]` variable to be 1.